# How to remove obsoleted logs with logrotate?

Tags: logs, cron, logrotate

I wanted to remove unnecessary logs automatically , like Xorg.log.0 , and other packed *.gz files , i really don't need that on a laptop system.

However , i checked `man logrotate` , but only an entry called `shred` , but irrelevant.

Comment: On a laptop do you really need to keep any logs? - You might consider switching off syslogd (to reduce writes) and deleting files from /tmp and /var/log at boot/shutdown. You might even consider putting these on a ramdisk or tmpfs

Comment: @symcbean: i can't use tmpfs as hibernation is often used , currently i'm redirecting kernel messages to /dev/tty12 , which is limited memory , without disk writing , so syslogd can't be turned off

Comment: Sorry @symcbean, but the idea to disable logging seems just stupid. The logs are there to *help* you. Getting rid of that facility for the mere purpose of increasing battery life by maybe a few percent sounds fanatic. If your logger does too much writes and does not ever let the drive spin down, then something is wrong with your configuration or system - and *that* is why you need logs.

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz , what about to reduce disk writing

Comment: @warl0ck [see edited comment above] It looks like swiping the dirt under the carpet instead of taking your shoes off.

Comment: To the heart of your question: could you please paste your `/etc/logrotate.conf`?

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz , there's too many files included in /etc/logrotate.d , which part are you looking for exactly ?

Comment: Mainly the ones with the word *rotate*. They can be both in `/etc/logrotate.conf` and `/etc/logrotate.d/*` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing old logs is the main job of `logrotate`. The number of old log versions kept on your disk is set by the `rotate` config option.

Also, take a look at the configuration files (`/etc/logrotate.conf`  and `/etc/logrotate.d/*`) as well as `man logrotate` to see various ways how the rotation can be triggered (like `monthly` or by size limit).